# .Net core Application Development in Windows using VS 2017 and Hosting in Mac os and Linux

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I was new to .Net core and on googling i got that it was used to develop an .net application that can run in corss platform other than windows i.e. Linux, Mac Osx.

I was having few questions on this,

1. What are pre-requistes softwares that i need to install to run .net application with respectivie specific OS i.e in Linux and in Mac os to run .net Core
2. Can we develop .net core application in Windows and host it in Mac and Linux if yes than how can we host.
3. Already Developed .net application, how can we migrate it to .net core without doing any changes and deploy in different env i.e Linux/Mac.

Can some one please address above questions,

As i was in a sutiation where i need to use existing .net application with signalR running  in Windows has to be made compatiable for Mac OSX and run it, Which was high priority. For this, Which one i need to Use weather .net core or Mono Project?

Please address on this. Thank you

Regards,
Siva

Comment: is existing .NET application developed in dotnet Core? if so you don't need to migrate it. 
If it is not in dotnet core, you need to identify the changes and compatibility with existing code and update the configuration from .NET to .NETCore , rebuild and test your app

Comment: you are probably looking for .NET core. start here - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/hello-world-tutorial/intro

Answer (score 0):

An answer to a few of your questions is to first off download the dotnet core runtime from Microsoft for you particular platform.

https://www.microsoft.com/net

I recently got this working on a raspberry pi of all things. Once you have the runtime you essentially just run the compiled .dll.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

The above should make is abundantly more clear than I can.